# How can I create podspec for private Github repo?

Tags: github, cocoapods

I'm able to run `pod spec create my_pod github.com/xyz/my_pod` to create my my_pod.podspec file for a public Github repo, but when I run the same command and my_pod is a private repo, I get 404.

`` [!] Unable to fetch data for `xyz/my_pod`
 [!] Request to https://api.github.com/repos/xyz/my_pod failed - 404
 [!] Not Found ``

I'm able to push and pull to and from the private repo. Do I need to give pod access some how?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be a bug with pod. The workaround is:
run `pod spec create my_pod` w/o the private repo url and once the podspec file is generated, add the url into the source. Now everything works.